# OpenGL render doesnt render with the Panoramic Fisheye Lens?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera

I made a animation with a Panoramic Lens (Fisheye Equidistant) but i need to render it with the OpenGL render for preview purposes....
But how can i activate that type of camera? or is it impossible?
Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly this feature is not supported. Here is a snippet from the Wiki:

> ***Cycles*** supports Equirectangular and Fisheye panoramic cameras. Note that *these **can't be displayed** with OpenGL* rendering in the viewport; they will only work for rendering.

[**Here is a link to the Blender wiki page on Cameras > >**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Camera)